# Public member 'Author' on type 'clsBook' not found. why?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
Private Sub ShowCurrentRecord()

    txtBookID.Text = books(index).BookID        
    txtAuthor.Text = books(index).Author        
    txtTitle.Text = books(index).Title        
    txtPurchasePrice.Text = books(index).PurchasePrice        
    txtSalePrice.Text = books(index).SalePrice        
    txtInventory.Text = books(index).Inventory
```

Public member 'Author' on type 'clsBook' is not found.

this is the code I used in the class...

```
Public Property AuthorID() As String

        Get    
            Return bookAuthor    
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As String)   
            bookAuthor = value    
        End Set

End Property
```

still, it doesn't work. T.T

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect us to tell you why. Study your own code and find out if `clsBook` really doesn't have any `Author`.

Comment: The error message seems pretty self explanatory: `Public member 'Author' on type 'clsBook' is not found`. What do you expect from us? Repeat the error message that the compiler already gives you?

Answer (score 3):

It means what the error says. There is not a public property named `Author` on your `clsBook` class. You are trying to access this property in the second line; and therefore, the compiler is complaining.

Try adding the property to the class; or remove the statement using it; and it will compile.

In response to your update: Your property on the class is named `AuthorID` (ID in the end) while you are trying to access `Author` (no ID in the end of the name).

Comment: You have a property named `AuthorID` but you are trying to use a property named  `Author`. That will not compile.